# I Stopped Losing Reputation when Voting Down

Tags: support, voting

I noticed that recently (at least for a week), I don't lose the normal 1 point of reputation when downvoting a question (not CW).  Has this been happening to others recently?  Is there something in the rules of this site that explains this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [they have changed the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927). Down-voting questions does not effect the reputation of the down voter any more.

You can also rigger a reputation recalculation [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/reputation).

Comment: Your second link is broken.

Comment: @Anthony, thanks, fixed.

Answer (score -4):

fyi the current cs faq seems to be incorrect (out of date) on that. it says:

> answer is voted down    -2  (-1 to voter)

reading kaveh's link they changed this to encourage more voting overall, but I am not sure thats the best choice. seems like maybe some forums might want to be able to independently adj some of these parameters.

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: the question is about down voting questions, the faq you quote is about down voting answers.